# Jquery.min.map File 404 in MVC4 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have IIS 6.2 running a C# MVC4 application and I keep getting a jquery.min.map 404 error in Google Chrome. I do not get the same error in IE9. I have the uncompressed jquery file along with the minified one and the map all in my scripts directory controlled by a NuGet package. Is there something specific with Chrome that could be causing this or is there something else I can look into? It looks like all my references are correct (I'm including it in the Bundler, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today.  The .map file wasn't being published.  The solution was to right click on the .map file in Visual Studio and select properties.  Note that the Build Action is `None`.  Change `None` to `Content` and the .map file will be included when you publish.

Answer (score -1):

You need to run Re-minify AA CSS/JS/HTML Files in Web Essentials.
Download [here](http://vswebessentials.com/).